# Creating a treeview of a folder structure over 60gb in size

Tags: c#, asp.net, lazy-loading

I need to add a folder structure (list the folder and filenames in its hierarchy) to an ASP.NET treeview control.

However, this folder structure is over 60gb. As you can imagine, doing this slows down my machine greatly.

Is there a way to do this elegantly? E.g. using lazy loading?

I am using .NET 3.5.

Thanks

Comment: http://ckfinder.com/demo may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You nailed it: use lazy loading. Have a look at the “Populating Nodes on Demand” section of [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178258%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).